# Which tense should I use with so far in the following sentences?

Tags: present-tense

How many ice creams did you eat/have you eaten in the morning so far?

Comment: *Ice cream* is usually a mass noun, not a countable one, so we would say **How much ice cream**, not **How many ice creams**.

Comment: @stangdon is correct in my opinion, however, there are places and people whereby an ice cream cone is called simply an "ice cream" and as such, a statement like, "We went for ice creams yesterday" is normal.

Comment: I strongly disagree with stangdon. In my (BrE) speech "How many ice creams" is completely normal.

Comment: @ColinFine It may be a US/UK thing.  I'm not going to say I've *never* heard somebody say "how many ice creams", but it is distinctly unusual here.

Answer (score 3):

In my (British English) speech, only *have you eaten* is possible with "so far" in this sentence.

My impression is that for many AmE speakers, *did you eat* would work too, but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: And 'so far this morning'.